# Hibernate 6 addScalar for mapping json column to a pojo

Tags: entitymanager, spring-boot-3, hibernate-native-query, hibernate-6.x, hibernate-types

I am trying to migrate from SpringBoot 2 to 3.
Previously, with the help of hibernate types we could run native queries and map the result to a POJO like so:

```
        var sp = dbService.nativeQueryBuilder("select id, json_column as \"jsonColumn\" from test_table")
                .unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
                .addScalar("id", StandardBasicTypes.LONG) // LongType.INSTANCE for SpringBoot 2
                .addScalar("jsonColumn", new JsonBinaryType(TestTabel.SomeJson.class))
                .setResultListTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(SomeJsonResult.class));

        return dbService.executeAndReturnListResult(sp, SomeJsonResult.class);
```

Note: dbService is just a wrapper over `EntityManager`.
In Hibernate 6 however, `.addScalar("jsonColumn", new JsonBinaryType(TestTabel.SomeJson.class))` is not working anymore.
Is there a workaround or a real solution?
jsonColumn is of type `jsonb` (PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix it.
Instead of using

```
.addScalar("jsonColumn", new JsonBinaryType(TestTabel.SomeJson.class))
```

you have to use:

```
.addScalar("someJson", new CustomType<>(
     new JsonBinaryType(TestTabel.SomeJson.class), new TypeConfiguration()))
```